# Как правильно реализовать выбор нужного Activity?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-shared-preferences

Есть приложение с активити авторизации и с активити для клиентских операций. Стоит ли создавать лаунчер-активити, который будет читать SharedPreferences и открывать нужную активити или есть другой, правильный способ?

Comment: Почему просто не сделать точкой входа авторизационный активити? Если авторизация прошла успешно, то создаем intent для запуска  клиентской активити. sharedPreferences  нужен для сохранения настроект приложения, думаю для данной задачи он не подходит.

Comment: Приложение должно работать еще и в оффлайн-режиме

Comment: Так, а причем тут `sharedPreferences` в контексте выбора активити? Пишите в `sharedPreferences` идентификатор последней авторизации и проверяйте его наличие. Если идентификатор присутствует - intent для запуска клиентской активити, иначе не пускать дальше авторизационной части. Но `sharedPreferences` может оказаться не лучшем решением для хранения подобных данных, так как данное хранилище представляет из себя обычный файл. Зависит от того, с какими данными нужно работать. Возможно лучше использовать другие средства.

Comment: Возможно [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SecurityFeatures) подойдет.

Comment: Я собирался в sharedPreferences записывать еще сам факт успешной авторизации и при следующем запуске проверочной активити, если бы отсутсвоало соединение и AuthState стояло в положении 'true',  загружалась бы клиентская активити.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте всегда активити авторизации, в `onCreate()` читайте свои настройки, если авторизация уже пройдена просто сразу открывайте следующие активити и это закрывайте если нет оставляйте это.

П.С. А вообще очень часто используют так званые SplashScreen активити, это просто заставка с логотипом что то вроде такого. Этот экран висит пару секунд и открывает следующий после себя. Можно создать такой экран в методе `onCreate()` запустить что то такое

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (authorized) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ClientActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, 2000);//Ставите сколько сек, 1000 = 1с.
```

Comment: Пару дней назад уже все реализовал в сплэш-активити =)